# Find text in <td> nth-child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check text in `<td>` nth-child.

I did :

```
alert($(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2):contains('New Scheduling')"));
```

Alert showing `[object] [object]`. How to get `True/False`?

```js
alert($(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2):contains('New Scheduling')"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">



  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Title"></a>EzLabor Code</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="EzLabor Code"
    FieldInternalName="Title"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
        test


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Project_x0020_Title"></a>Project Description</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Project Description"
    FieldInternalName="Project_x0020_Title"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
        test


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Date_x0020_Requested"></a>Request Date</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
        <!-- FieldName="Request Date"
    FieldInternalName="Date_x0020_Requested"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
        5/8/2018&nbsp;


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Start_x0020_Date"></a>Due Date</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
        <!-- FieldName="Due Date"
    FieldInternalName="Start_x0020_Date"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
        5/8/2018&nbsp;


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Marketing_x002f_Project_x0020_Ma"></a>Marketing/Project Manager</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldUserMulti">
        <!-- FieldName="Marketing/Project Manager"
    FieldInternalName="Marketing_x002f_Project_x0020_Ma"
    FieldType="SPFieldUserMulti"
    -->
        <nobr><span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event); return false;" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink" tabindex="-1"><span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" showofflinepawn="1" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" sip="" id="imn0,type=sip"></span></a>
          </span><span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event); return false;" class="ms-imnlink" tabindex="-1"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" class="ms-hide" showofflinepawn="1" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" sip="" id="imn1,type=sip"></a><a onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this); return false;" class="ms-peopleux-userdisplink ms-subtleLink" href="/dept/wc/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={4d24aff7-9486-4883-87e2-271651194a4c}&amp;ID=21">Srikanth Vadlakonda</a></span></nobr>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Select_x0020_Here"></a>Type of Request (Please Select)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Type of Request (Please Select)"
    FieldInternalName="Select_x0020_Here"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        Training Course Page


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Training_x0020_Courses"></a>Training Courses (Please Select)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Training Courses (Please Select)"
    FieldInternalName="Training_x0020_Courses"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        New Scheduling of Training Course (includes details on left side)


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Is_x0020_this_x0020_a_x0020_Trai"></a>Is this a Training Course or Seminar?</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Is this a Training Course or Seminar?"
    FieldInternalName="Is_x0020_this_x0020_a_x0020_Trai"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        Training Course


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Title0"></a>Title</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Title"
    FieldInternalName="Title0"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
        N/A


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Technical_x0020_Discipline_x0028"></a>Technical Discipline(s)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldMultiChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Technical Discipline(s)"
    FieldInternalName="Technical_x0020_Discipline_x0028"
    FieldType="SPFieldMultiChoice"
    -->
        Completions


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Description"></a>Course Description (attach file if needed)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Course Description (attach file if needed)"
    FieldInternalName="Description"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
        <div class="ms-rtestate-field">
          <div dir="">
            <div class="ExternalClass77CDADB3DBD54D56AE9F0B4497948B3E">
              <p>N/A</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Learning_x0020_Level"></a>Learning Level</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Learning Level"
    FieldInternalName="Learning_x0020_Level"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        Introductory


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Course_x0020_Length"></a>Course Length</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Course Length"
    FieldInternalName="Course_x0020_Length"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
        N/A


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Why_x0020_Attend"></a>Why Attend</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Why Attend"
    FieldInternalName="Why_x0020_Attend"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
        <div class="ms-rtestate-field">
          <div dir="">
            <div class="ExternalClass3B73CED3A9B54E11A6C6A637FCB42858">
              <p>N/A</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Who_x0020_Should_x0020_Attend"></a>Who Should Attend</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Who Should Attend"
    FieldInternalName="Who_x0020_Should_x0020_Attend"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
        <div class="ms-rtestate-field">
          <div dir="">
            <div class="ExternalClass869FCB4EA8F64F7BA8A94EBF4120DF97">
              <p>N/A</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_CEUs"></a>CEUs</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldMultiChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="CEUs"
    FieldInternalName="CEUs"
    FieldType="SPFieldMultiChoice"
    -->
        .4


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Cancellation_x0020_Policy"></a>Cancellation Policy</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Cancellation Policy"
    FieldInternalName="Cancellation_x0020_Policy"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Special_x0020_Requirements"></a>Special Requirements</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldMultiChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Special Requirements"
    FieldInternalName="Special_x0020_Requirements"
    FieldType="SPFieldMultiChoice"
    -->
        Students will need to bring laptops


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Instructor_x0020_Name_x0028_s_x0"></a>Instructor Name(s)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Instructor Name(s)"
    FieldInternalName="Instructor_x0020_Name_x0028_s_x0"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
        srikanth vadlakonda


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark__x2022__x0009_Instructor_x0020_B"></a>Instructor Bio</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Instructor Bio"
    FieldInternalName="_x2022__x0009_Instructor_x0020_B"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
        <div class="ms-rtestate-field">
          <div dir="">
            <div class="ExternalClass0A4AF216358745478A3D31BE1A6828F5">
              <p>&#8203;test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_URL_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_pag"></a>URL of the page</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="URL of the page"
    FieldInternalName="URL_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_pag"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Would_x0020_you_x0020_like_x0020"></a>Would you like to add a Training Course Occurrence/Add Date and Registration Info?</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Would you like to add a Training Course Occurrence/Add Date and Registration Info?"
    FieldInternalName="Would_x0020_you_x0020_like_x0020"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        No


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Training_x0020_Course_x0020_Date"></a>Training Course Date</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
        <!-- FieldName="Training Course Date"
    FieldInternalName="Training_x0020_Course_x0020_Date"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Location_x0020__x0028_Venue_x002"></a>Location (Venue and City)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Location (Venue and City)"
    FieldInternalName="Location_x0020__x0028_Venue_x002"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Conference_x0020_Name"></a>Conference Name</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Conference Name"
    FieldInternalName="Conference_x0020_Name"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Early_x0020_Bird_x0020_Registrat"></a>Early Bird Registration Date</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
        <!-- FieldName="Early Bird Registration Date"
    FieldInternalName="Early_x0020_Bird_x0020_Registrat"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Course_x0020_Registration_x0020_"></a>Course Registration URL (If no registration link is available at this time, Coming Soon image will be used.)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Course Registration URL (If no registration link is available at this time, Coming Soon image will be used.)"
    FieldInternalName="Course_x0020_Registration_x0020_"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_1"></a>Corresponding Event Name (If applicable)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event Name (If applicable)"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_1"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_2"></a>Corresponding Event URL (If applicable)</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event URL (If applicable)"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_2"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Is_x0020_this_x0020_Training_x00"></a>Is this Training Course held in conjunction with another event?</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Is this Training Course held in conjunction with another event?"
    FieldInternalName="Is_x0020_this_x0020_Training_x00"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        No


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_"></a>Corresponding Event Name</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event Name"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_0"></a>Corresponding Event URL</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event URL"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_0"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Priority"></a>EMERGENCY</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="EMERGENCY"
    FieldInternalName="Priority"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        No


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Details_x002f_Special_x0020_Inst"></a>Details/Special Instructions</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Details/Special Instructions"
    FieldInternalName="Details_x002f_Special_x0020_Inst"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Current_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"></a>Current Text/Content</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Current Text/Content"
    FieldInternalName="Current_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_New_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"></a>New Text/Content</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="New Text/Content"
    FieldInternalName="New_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Project_x0020_Assigned_x0020_To"></a>Project Assigned To</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Project Assigned To"
    FieldInternalName="Project_x0020_Assigned_x0020_To"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        SPEHQ\webcontent


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Date_x0020_Completed"></a>Date Completed</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
        <!-- FieldName="Date Completed"
    FieldInternalName="Date_x0020_Completed"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Status"></a>Status</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Status"
    FieldInternalName="Status"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        Not started


      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Status_x0020_Comments"></a>Status Comments</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
        <!-- FieldName="Status Comments"
    FieldInternalName="Status_x0020_Comments"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_tjil"></a>Person or Group</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldUser">
        <!-- FieldName="Person or Group"
    FieldInternalName="tjil"
    FieldType="SPFieldUser"
    -->



      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Attachment_x003f_"></a>Attachment?</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
        <!-- FieldName="Attachment?"
    FieldInternalName="Attachment_x003f_"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
        No


      </td>
    </tr>



    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow" style="display: none;">

      <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
          <a name="SPBookmark_Attachments"></a>Attachments</h3>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldAttachments">
        <!-- FieldName="Attachments"
    FieldInternalName="Attachments"
    FieldType="SPFieldAttachments"
    -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="idAttachmentsTable"></table>


      </td>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[ 


        if (typeof ShowAttachmentRows == "function")
          ShowAttachmentRows();
        // ]]>
      </script>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: to debug, use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, it should show the object as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a selector to JQuery always returns a JQuery "wrapped set" object  (whether or not any elements were actually found) and that's what your `alert()` is showing you. What you care about is if there is anything in that set. To test that, you can look at the `.length` property and test if it is `> 0`. If so, you know that at least one element was found and is in the set:

```js
alert($(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2):contains('New Scheduling')").length > 0);
alert($(".ms-formtable tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2):contains('Something that won\' be found.')").length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      
      
                        
  <tbody><tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Title"></a>EzLabor Code</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="EzLabor Code"
    FieldInternalName="Title"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   test
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Project_x0020_Title"></a>Project Description</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Project Description"
    FieldInternalName="Project_x0020_Title"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   test
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Date_x0020_Requested"></a>Request Date</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
  <!-- FieldName="Request Date"
    FieldInternalName="Date_x0020_Requested"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
   5/8/2018&nbsp;
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Start_x0020_Date"></a>Due Date</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
  <!-- FieldName="Due Date"
    FieldInternalName="Start_x0020_Date"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
   5/8/2018&nbsp;
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Marketing_x002f_Project_x0020_Ma"></a>Marketing/Project Manager</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldUserMulti">
  <!-- FieldName="Marketing/Project Manager"
    FieldInternalName="Marketing_x002f_Project_x0020_Ma"
    FieldType="SPFieldUserMulti"
    -->
   <nobr><span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event); return false;" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink" tabindex="-1"><span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" showofflinepawn="1" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" sip="" id="imn0,type=sip"></span></a></span><span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event); return false;" class="ms-imnlink" tabindex="-1"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" class="ms-hide" showofflinepawn="1" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" sip="" id="imn1,type=sip"></a><a onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this); return false;" class="ms-peopleux-userdisplink ms-subtleLink" href="/dept/wc/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={4d24aff7-9486-4883-87e2-271651194a4c}&amp;ID=21">Srikanth Vadlakonda</a></span></nobr>
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Select_x0020_Here"></a>Type of Request (Please Select)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Type of Request (Please Select)"
    FieldInternalName="Select_x0020_Here"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   Training Course Page
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Training_x0020_Courses"></a>Training Courses (Please Select)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Training Courses (Please Select)"
    FieldInternalName="Training_x0020_Courses"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   New Scheduling of Training Course (includes details on left side)
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Is_x0020_this_x0020_a_x0020_Trai"></a>Is this a Training Course or Seminar?</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Is this a Training Course or Seminar?"
    FieldInternalName="Is_x0020_this_x0020_a_x0020_Trai"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   Training Course
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Title0"></a>Title</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Title"
    FieldInternalName="Title0"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   N/A
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Technical_x0020_Discipline_x0028"></a>Technical Discipline(s)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldMultiChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Technical Discipline(s)"
    FieldInternalName="Technical_x0020_Discipline_x0028"
    FieldType="SPFieldMultiChoice"
    -->
   Completions
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Description"></a>Course Description (attach file if needed)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Course Description (attach file if needed)"
    FieldInternalName="Description"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   <div class="ms-rtestate-field"><div dir=""><div class="ExternalClass77CDADB3DBD54D56AE9F0B4497948B3E"><p>N/A</p></div></div></div>
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Learning_x0020_Level"></a>Learning Level</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Learning Level"
    FieldInternalName="Learning_x0020_Level"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   Introductory
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Course_x0020_Length"></a>Course Length</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Course Length"
    FieldInternalName="Course_x0020_Length"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   N/A
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Why_x0020_Attend"></a>Why Attend</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Why Attend"
    FieldInternalName="Why_x0020_Attend"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   <div class="ms-rtestate-field"><div dir=""><div class="ExternalClass3B73CED3A9B54E11A6C6A637FCB42858"><p>N/A</p></div></div></div>
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Who_x0020_Should_x0020_Attend"></a>Who Should Attend</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Who Should Attend"
    FieldInternalName="Who_x0020_Should_x0020_Attend"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   <div class="ms-rtestate-field"><div dir=""><div class="ExternalClass869FCB4EA8F64F7BA8A94EBF4120DF97"><p>N/A</p></div></div></div>
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_CEUs"></a>CEUs</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldMultiChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="CEUs"
    FieldInternalName="CEUs"
    FieldType="SPFieldMultiChoice"
    -->
   .4
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Cancellation_x0020_Policy"></a>Cancellation Policy</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Cancellation Policy"
    FieldInternalName="Cancellation_x0020_Policy"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Special_x0020_Requirements"></a>Special Requirements</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldMultiChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Special Requirements"
    FieldInternalName="Special_x0020_Requirements"
    FieldType="SPFieldMultiChoice"
    -->
   Students will need to bring laptops
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Instructor_x0020_Name_x0028_s_x0"></a>Instructor Name(s)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Instructor Name(s)"
    FieldInternalName="Instructor_x0020_Name_x0028_s_x0"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   srikanth vadlakonda
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark__x2022__x0009_Instructor_x0020_B"></a>Instructor Bio</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Instructor Bio"
    FieldInternalName="_x2022__x0009_Instructor_x0020_B"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   <div class="ms-rtestate-field"><div dir=""><div class="ExternalClass0A4AF216358745478A3D31BE1A6828F5"><p>&#8203;test</p></div></div></div>
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_URL_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_pag"></a>URL of the page</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="URL of the page"
    FieldInternalName="URL_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_pag"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Would_x0020_you_x0020_like_x0020"></a>Would you like to add a Training Course Occurrence/Add Date and Registration Info?</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Would you like to add a Training Course Occurrence/Add Date and Registration Info?"
    FieldInternalName="Would_x0020_you_x0020_like_x0020"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   No
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Training_x0020_Course_x0020_Date"></a>Training Course Date</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
  <!-- FieldName="Training Course Date"
    FieldInternalName="Training_x0020_Course_x0020_Date"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Location_x0020__x0028_Venue_x002"></a>Location (Venue and City)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Location (Venue and City)"
    FieldInternalName="Location_x0020__x0028_Venue_x002"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Conference_x0020_Name"></a>Conference Name</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Conference Name"
    FieldInternalName="Conference_x0020_Name"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Early_x0020_Bird_x0020_Registrat"></a>Early Bird Registration Date</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
  <!-- FieldName="Early Bird Registration Date"
    FieldInternalName="Early_x0020_Bird_x0020_Registrat"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Course_x0020_Registration_x0020_"></a>Course Registration URL (If no registration link is available at this time, Coming Soon image will be used.)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Course Registration URL (If no registration link is available at this time, Coming Soon image will be used.)"
    FieldInternalName="Course_x0020_Registration_x0020_"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_1"></a>Corresponding Event Name (If applicable)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event Name (If applicable)"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_1"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_2"></a>Corresponding Event URL (If applicable)</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event URL (If applicable)"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_2"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Is_x0020_this_x0020_Training_x00"></a>Is this Training Course held in conjunction with another event?</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Is this Training Course held in conjunction with another event?"
    FieldInternalName="Is_x0020_this_x0020_Training_x00"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   No
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_"></a>Corresponding Event Name</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event Name"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_0"></a>Corresponding Event URL</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
  <!-- FieldName="Corresponding Event URL"
    FieldInternalName="Corresponding_x0020_Event_x0020_0"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Priority"></a>EMERGENCY</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="EMERGENCY"
    FieldInternalName="Priority"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   No
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Details_x002f_Special_x0020_Inst"></a>Details/Special Instructions</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Details/Special Instructions"
    FieldInternalName="Details_x002f_Special_x0020_Inst"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Current_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"></a>Current Text/Content</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Current Text/Content"
    FieldInternalName="Current_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_New_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"></a>New Text/Content</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="New Text/Content"
    FieldInternalName="New_x0020_Text_x002f_Content"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Project_x0020_Assigned_x0020_To"></a>Project Assigned To</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Project Assigned To"
    FieldInternalName="Project_x0020_Assigned_x0020_To"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   SPEHQ\webcontent
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Date_x0020_Completed"></a>Date Completed</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldDateTime">
  <!-- FieldName="Date Completed"
    FieldInternalName="Date_x0020_Completed"
    FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Status"></a>Status</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Status"
    FieldInternalName="Status"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   Not started
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Status_x0020_Comments"></a>Status Comments</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldNote">
  <!-- FieldName="Status Comments"
    FieldInternalName="Status_x0020_Comments"
    FieldType="SPFieldNote"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_tjil"></a>Person or Group</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldUser">
  <!-- FieldName="Person or Group"
    FieldInternalName="tjil"
    FieldType="SPFieldUser"
    -->
   
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Attachment_x003f_"></a>Attachment?</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
  <!-- FieldName="Attachment?"
    FieldInternalName="Attachment_x003f_"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
   No
    
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
      
      
  <tr id="idAttachmentsRow" style="display: none;">
   
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Attachments"></a>Attachments</h3></td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldAttachments">
  <!-- FieldName="Attachments"
    FieldInternalName="Attachments"
    FieldType="SPFieldAttachments"
    -->
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="idAttachmentsTable"></table>
    
   
  </td>
 
   <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ 


    if (typeof ShowAttachmentRows == "function")
     ShowAttachmentRows();
   // ]]>
</script>
  </tr>
 
      </tbody></table>
```